# PHP string convert

Tags: php, regex

I'm sorry, but I speak a little English.

I use:

```
$file = file_get_content ( 'cfg.php' );
```

The cfg.php file example:

```
$pw = 'abcdefgh';
$user = 12345678;
```

I would like convert to string this PHP file, because I would like use:

```
$pattern = "/\$(?<name>.+?) = '(?<value>.+?)';/";

if ( preg_match_all ( $pattern, $file, $matches ) ) {

    foreach ( $matches [ 'name' ] as $key => $value ) {

        print $value . ' = ' . $matches [ 'value' ] [ $key ] . '<br>';

    }

} else {}
```

I would like see:

```
pw = abcdefgh
user = 12345678
```

I think the problem is the dollar $ signs because run PHP, but I would like no PHP, only string the $file.

Please help me, thanks.

Comment: Try single quotes round your `$pattern`.

Comment: Dear Nigel Ren, It works with single quotes, but if I use: '/\$(?<name>.+?) = '(?<value>.+?)';/' it not works.

Comment: use : `$pattern = '/\$(?<name>.+?) = (?<value>.+?);/';`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to multiple escape the backslashes:

```php
$file =<<<'EOD'
$pw = 'abcdefgh';
$user = 12345678;
EOD;

$pattern = "/\\$(?<name>.+?) = ('?)(?<value>.+?)\\2;/";
if ( preg_match_all ( $pattern, $file, $matches ) ) {
    foreach ( $matches [ 'name' ] as $key => $value ) {
        print $value . ' = ' . $matches [ 'value' ] [ $key ] . '<br>';
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
pw = abcdefgh<br>user = 12345678<br>
```